# Is it possible to create Oracle Packages dynamically from a win app

Tags: .net, oracle, package

I created an app in VB.NET that builds procedures for a package from user input.  They can then copy and paste them into Oracle via SQL Developer or TOAD.

Is it possible for it to connect to Oracle and append the code to an existing package and then compile it?

Are there existing Oracle or .net tools for that or will it have to be done by hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can.
First get the current definition using dbms_metdata.get_ddl, edit the text you get and apply that using regular dynamic sql.

use `dbms_metadata.get_ddl (object_type, object_name, USER);`
do that for 'PACKAGE BODY' to only get and change that. If you use PACKAGE as an object type, you get both the package specification and body.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability to execute SQL you can do everything you need.
Just send them as individual SQL statements.

You can use the [Oracle .NET Provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)

GUI tools just hide the SQL Meta Data command to pull everything off.

For example you can use the following to compile an existing package.

[ALTER PACKAGE YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME COMPILE PACKAGE;](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/statements_2005.htm)